# changing the text on the fa-money icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to change the number value on [font awesome's fa-money icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/money/) to 750 (instead of 1). Longer term I'll be setting it dynamically, but I can rely on 3 characters of space being required.

I think the answer might be [stacked icons as noted in this font awesome blog post](http://blog.fontawesome.io/2014/05/19/stacking-text-and-icons/), but I haven't been able to get the formatting right.

The customization from the blog post above looks like this:

```
  <span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
    <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <strong class="fa-stack-1x fa-stack-text file-text">16</strong>
  </span>
```

But again, when I try my best hack-job on the fa-money, it looks like a jumbled mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the '1' on the money-icon isn't editable, it's 'hard-designed' so you can't just change the number on that one. The other examples on the blog post you posted don't have any numbers in them so it's easy to add with the trick you posted.

There is an 'hack' tough. You can add your own icons to fontawesome, so make a icon like the money icon but remove the inner number. Then once added to fontawesome you can set the number with the trick you tried yourself.

Take a look at https://icomoon.io to see how to add icons. Best of luck!